# Python import modules from a higher level package

Tags: python, package, python-import, python-module

This is my package hierarchy

```
app  
|--__init__.py    //Empty file
|--server.py  
|--global_vars.py  
|
|--handlers    
   |--__init__.py    //Empty file
   |
   |--url1
   |  |--__init__.py    //Empty file
   |  |--app1.py
   |  |--app2.py
   |
   |--url2
      |--__init__.py    //Empty file
      |--app3.py
```

Now I want to import `global_vars.py` inside `app1.py`.
So I gave 
    `import app.global_vars.py` inside app1.py.

But I get the following error:

```
    import app.global_vars
ImportError: No module named app.global_vars
```

I should also mention that I am importing app1.py from server.py. `server.py` is the file I am actually running. When server.py imports app1.py, `app1.py` tries to import `global_vars.py` and I get the above mentioned error

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is there a `__init__.py` file in `app`?

Comment: Yes, there is a `__init__.py` in all the directories in the given file heirarchy

Comment: What does `import app; print app.__file__` say is the path to that module / package?

Comment: I went to app's parent folder, opened a python shell and imported app.
  Now `app.__file__` gives `app/__init__.py` as output

Comment: No, I wanted you to do that in `app1.py`.

Comment: `ImportError: No module named app`

Comment: Did you at any point use `os.chdir()` to change the current directory anywhere in your code?

Comment: I should mention that I am importing `app1.py` from `server.py`. server.py is the file I am actually running. When server.py imports app1.py, `app1.py` tries to import `global_vars.py` and I get the above mentioned error

Comment: No, I have not used any such thing

Comment: That is a crucial piece of information. Scripts have their own directory added to `sys.path`, *not* the package they are in.

Comment: So, how should I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are running `app/server.py` as a script, the parent directory of `app` is not added to `sys.path()`. The `app` directory itself is added instead (not as a package but as a import search path).

You have 4 options:

1. Move `server.py` *out* of the `app` package (next to it)
2. Add a new script file next to `app` that only runs:

   ```
   from app import server
   server.main()
   ```
3. Use the [`-m` switch option](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m) to run a *module* as the main entry point:

   ```
   python -m app.server
   ```
4. Add the parent directory of `server.py` to `sys.path`:

   ```
   import os.path
   import sys

   parent = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
   sys.path.insert(0, parent)
   ```

   This last option can introduce more problems however; now both the `app` package and the modules contained *in* the `app` package are on `sys.path`. You can import both `app.server` and `server` and Python will see these as two separate modules, each with their own entry in `sys.modules`, with separate copies of their globals.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Now, I understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

need `__init__.py` file, will regard it as a package

app
|--server.py
|--global_vars.py
|--handlers

|--`__init__.py`
...

`__init__.py` can be empty

Comment: There is a `__init__.py` in all the directories in the given file heirarchy